# Convert sequence list to fasta for multiple files

Tags: awk, bioinformatics, fasta

I have thousands of files, which are a list of sequence names followed by their sequence, one individual per line, something like this:

```
L.abdalai.LJAMM.14363.SanMartindeLosAndes        CCCTAAGAATAATTTGTT
L.carlosgarini.LJAMM.14070.LagunadelMaule        CCCTAAGAAT-ATTTGTT
L.cf.silvai.DD.038.Sarco                         CCCTAAGAAT-ATTTGTT
```

And I want to change them to fasta format, so looking something like:

```
>L.abdalai.LJAMM.14363.SanMartindeLosAndes       
CCCTAAGAATAATTTGTTCAGAAAAGATATTTAATTATAT
>L.carlosgarini.LJAMM.14070.LagunadelMaule
CCCTAAGAAT-ATTTGTTCAGAAAAGATATTTAATTATAT
>L.cf.silvai.DD.038.Sarco
CCCTAAGAAT-ATTTGTTCAGAAAAGATATTTAATTATAT
```

I work on a Mac.
Thanks!

Comment: Try with 'awk' tag

Comment: 'CAGAAAAGATATTTAATTATAT' string, Where it comes from?

Comment: Do you want each sequence to be saved to its own individual file? If so how should they be named? How are the thousands of source files named?

Comment: Hi Shawn, yes, I want each sequence to be saved to a separate file. The original names are part1.txt, part2.txt.. and so on. The new names can be the same or whatever, loci1, loci2, etc...

Answer (score 2):

Using Perl

```
perl -pe 's/^/</;s/(\S+)\s+(\S+)/$1\n$2CAGAAAAGATATTTAATTATAT/g ' file
```

with your inputs

```
$ cat damien.txt
L.abdalai.LJAMM.14363.SanMartindeLosAndes        CCCTAAGAATAATTTGTT
L.carlosgarini.LJAMM.14070.LagunadelMaule        CCCTAAGAAT-ATTTGTT
L.cf.silvai.DD.038.Sarco                         CCCTAAGAAT-ATTTGTT

$ perl -pe 's/^/</;s/(\S+)\s+(\S+)/$1\n$2CAGAAAAGATATTTAATTATAT/g ' damien.txt
<L.abdalai.LJAMM.14363.SanMartindeLosAndes
CCCTAAGAATAATTTGTTCAGAAAAGATATTTAATTATAT
<L.carlosgarini.LJAMM.14070.LagunadelMaule
CCCTAAGAAT-ATTTGTTCAGAAAAGATATTTAATTATAT
<L.cf.silvai.DD.038.Sarco
CCCTAAGAAT-ATTTGTTCAGAAAAGATATTTAATTATAT

$
```

Answer (score 2):

I believe you simplied your sample input, thus different from your expected output.
If not so, and my solutions not work, please comment under my answer to let me know.

So with awk, you can do it like this:

```
awk -v OFS="\n" '$1=">" $1' file
>L.abdalai.LJAMM.14363.SanMartindeLosAndes
CCCTAAGAATAATTTGTT
>L.carlosgarini.LJAMM.14070.LagunadelMaule
CCCTAAGAAT-ATTTGTT
>L.cf.silvai.DD.038.Sarco
CCCTAAGAAT-ATTTGTT
```

If you want to change inplace, please install GNU gawk, and use `gawk -i inplace ....`
And if you want the line endings be *Carriages*, add/change to `-v ORS="\r" -v OFS="\r"`

However, you can also, and maybe it's better to do it with `sed`:

```
sed -e 's/\([^[:space:]]*\)[[:space:]]*\([^[:space:]]*\)/>\1\n\2/' file
```

Add `-i''` like this: `sed -i'' -e ...` to change file inplace.

Answer (score 1):

Could you please try following(created and tested based on your samples, since I don't have mac to didn't test on it).

```
awk '/^L\./{print ">"$1 ORS $2 "CAGAAAAGATATTTAATTATAT"}'  Input_file
```

Output will be as follows. If needed you could take it to a output_file by appending `> output_file` to above command too.

```
>L.abdalai.LJAMM.14363.SanMartindeLosAndes
CCCTAAGAATAATTTGTTCAGAAAAGATATTTAATTATAT
>L.carlosgarini.LJAMM.14070.LagunadelMaule
CCCTAAGAAT-ATTTGTTCAGAAAAGATATTTAATTATAT
>L.cf.silvai.DD.038.Sarco
CCCTAAGAAT-ATTTGTTCAGAAAAGATATTTAATTATAT
```

Comment: @Damien Esquerre, could you please do let me know if this helped you?